# Do mathematicians need logical thinking?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

Do mathematicians need logical thinking? I did well in undergraduate math but I only took an axiomatic approach. I've never done logic workbooks.

Comment: Don't worry about this. Logical thinking is not at all obtained "only" by taking logic courses or doing logic workbooks. I think this is a non-issue...

Comment: Workbooks?  I last saw a workbook when I was about 10.  Do you mean "read a textbook on logic" perhaps?

Comment: @TerryLoring Ok, it is chemistry and not mathematics; but workbooks are still around for school ([example](https://www.cambridge.org/us/education/subject/science/chemistry/cambridge-igcse-chemistry-4th-edition/cambridge-igcse-chemistry-4th-edition-digital-workbook-2-years-workbook?isbn=9781107614994)) and uni ([example](https://global.oup.com/ukhe/scienceresources/wic/?cc=gb&lang=en&)).

Comment: I find it hard to see how one can achieve anything in maths without logical thinking. I've always assumed that the rationale for teaching children Euclidean geometry was that it's all about deductive proof, which is surely the core of logical thinking.

Comment: @Buttonwood Also maths ([example](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masdbd/analysis/)).

Comment: Your question seems very confused. Yes, of course mathematicians need logical reasoning: logical reasoning is the methodology of mathematics. "I only took an axiomatic approach" - maybe I don't understand what you mean by "an axiomatic approach", but to me, taking an axiomatic approach to mathematics requires using a whole lot of logical reasoning. Maybe what you're asking is whether you need to know *formal logic* or *mathematical logic*. The answer to this is no: the majority of mathematicians have never had any training in formal logic.

Answer (score 14):

Mathematicians need a lot of things. Intuition, insight, and, yes, logical thinking. Proofs need to be rigorously connected to what is already known. That is logic.

I'd be surprised that, even if your background was heavy on axiomatic structures, you didn't need proofs. So, you probably have enough "logical thinking" to move forward if you studied undergraduate mathematics.

A course in formal logic is mathematical and fun, but it isn't all that is mathematics.

Comment: @anon: To elaborate on Buffy's answer, a possible analogy is "formal/mathematical logic is to mathematics as the Peano axioms are to accounting" (or replace "accounting" with any area that involves lots of arithmetic computations and good number sense). Roughly speaking, one can view the Peano axioms as a way of formalizing common-usage arithmetic notions to create a model of them that can then be formally studied, and formal/mathematical logic is a way of formalizing common-usage logical thinking notions to create a model of them that can then be formally studied.